# Instal ImageMagick on cpanel server

Tags: php, imagick

1 - I´m loged to server via SSH;

2 - I runned command `yum install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel pcre-devel`;

3 - I runned command `/usr/bin/convert --version`;

output:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-68 Q16 x86_64 2021-10-14 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP(3.1)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo fontconfig freetype gslib jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png ps rsvg tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

4 - my php version is 7.3.3;

5 - I runned command `/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/bin/pecl install imagick`;

output:

```
(***)
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/include/php/ext/imagick/php_imagick_sh                                                                                                                                                             ared.h'
Installing '/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/imagick-3.7.0
Extension imagick enabled in php.ini
```

6 - no `imagick` in `phpinfo()`;

WHM version: `102.0.10`;

What i missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to install any module in Cpanel is by using Module Installers

check this

https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360037048673-How-to-Install-ImageMagick-for-EA-PHP-and-ALT-PHP

also to make sure did you restart your web server after the installation?

Comment: Tnx Ahmed Hassan, restar of server helped and 5 step was by whm module installer

Comment: @VladyslavLevenets glad to know that, good luck